# Need advice about making a forum with php

Tags: php, mysql, forum

I am trying to create a forum on my page. I need some advice. I have MySQL database and I am able to to work with it. Yet as far as I can make is playing with POST. I mean on click submit a $_POST['submit']) becomes set and so on. Then connect to database, get info and display.This way of making a forum is bad, because it all happens on a single page. As far as I seen any other forum when entering one and so on has it's unique Uri (what comes after domain.com/) so you can simply send someone full url and they are in that thread (unlike if you play with $_POST['submit']).

Sorry if my question is not accurate and I am not asking to write me code. I just need someone to direct me to the right place and any advice would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: I'd advise you to not re-invent the wheel and use an existing forum-softwarepackage like [phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/). Creating a forum from scratch is quite a challenge, and from your question I assume you're not very familiar with programming yet.

Comment: In addition to what @FrankSunnyman said, I flagged the question as too broad.

Comment: I am not very advanced programmer and this is my first website so I just want to learn one or another thing and see how everything works.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but you did not display capability or knowledge proving your readiness to accept such a challenge. I suggest start with something a lot simpler.

Comment: it's ok. To be more accurate I just wanted to know this "wheel" Principe, because for some reason I couldn't find something like what you posted (phpBB) which as I see would solve my problem. Web programming is a new thing for me. I won't lie. Don't have much experience in it.

Comment: Unfortunately StackOverflow is a more direct-problem-question-type site, not for general advice, so people like to close questions like yours. But you will (with experience) learn how to ask more directly because asking here is totally related to the programming way of thinking. Always narrow down your problems to asking and to research. About your forum, you can use a basic two page setup. Main page pull alls the threads and displays. Then, each thread is a link to a thread page with an id (thread.php?id=123, thread.php?id=124).This page displays content based on its ID, using GET. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is difficult to understand, but I think you are confused about how data and pages are dynamic using GET/POST.

The URLS with different IDs are like an illusion. Really, its the same page, however the page is dynamically taking that ID from the URL, and using it to output certain data.

For example, say we habe the URL: `www.example.com/show_thread.php?thread=3`

The php would look like

```
if(isset($_GET['thread'])){
   $data = $db>query("SELECT thread_title,thread_text FROM threads WHERE thread_id = $_GET['thread']");

  print($data);

}
```

***Warning: do not use this exact code, it is an example, not secure, etc**

Then the database would look like

```
thread_id     thread_title         thread_text
1               kngwihywoihwy      kngwihywoihwykngwihywoihwy
2            vyfngoieyoiehyon     ieonuwrtoi hunwrmt jirwyji
3           nuoaiefguneoihn        eoithneiotheo
```

and the page would show

```
nuoaiefguneoihn        eoithneiotheo
```

POSTing data is for sending it to the server, and doing something with it. Just like GET. However, GET is helpful for passing things around as they are accessible in links. Like this example.

Comment: More or less what I was looking for about url. Thank You !

Comment: Great. happy to help